Error while evaluating property 'ifKaptClasspathIsPresent' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'
Using kotlin-kapt, room and coroutines dependecies in project with gradle version 8.3.2 and following errors occur. Build OutputBuild Output 2 Build Output 3
I've already tried to change JVM version of the project to 17,18 without any result.
Ran --warning-mode=all and got this output: warning mode all. Latest available version of gradle is 8.3.2 in Android Studio if I get it right.
Also tried to change kapt jvmTarget to 1.8 (same with my gradle) but it didn't help.
Tried to find the solution in plugins but only mentioned this issue with Koltin Extension Indexer: Kotlin Extension Indexer
I don't have much experience with such type of issues, so I definitely can't see something obvious or maybe this problem is about gradle/kotlin/dependencies versions compatibility.

you have to used follow version:
val roomVersion = "2.5.0"

implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

